# c# add columns to listbox and clear list items

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, listbox

I have a winforms app in C# in which the user must select data from a `combobox` those items are then listed in a `listbox`.
The problems I have are as follows:
If the user selects an item the result appear okay, but if he selects another item the old results wont get cleared so I use the line:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
```

However if I use this line of code, the results wont appear completely, there are lines missing.

The code I have is:

```
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select [desc],[enchimento] from vidros where desempenho = @emp", con);
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@emp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = desempenho.Text;
    DataTable DTT = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(DTT);

    for (int i = 0; i < DTT.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        DataRow dr = DTT.Rows[i];
        ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["desc"].ToString()); 
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["desc"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["enchimento"].ToString());
        listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
    }
```

The second problem is, i have 2 fields that i wish to display in the listbox, (desc and enchimento), but the listbox only displays one of them.

Comment: Maybe you could join them, for example: listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["desc"].ToString() + " "+dr["enchimento"].ToString());

Comment: I think there are select and unselect methods for listview.. Try with intellisense and I think there are possibilities to resolve your issue easily

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete thanks, that resolved the 2 items displaying. now i just need to clear old selections

Comment: I think you could apply a bit of this solution for the other part:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858565/check-only-one-listviewitem-at-time

Comment: By the way try this too:
string[] row1 = { "s1", "s2", "s3" };
listView1.Items.Add("Column1Text").SubItems.AddRange(row1);

I think you don't see the multiple columns because you're not using the AddRange:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473148/c-sharp-listview-how-do-i-add-items-to-columns-2-3-and-4-etc

Comment: You call `listView1.Items.Clear()` _inside the loop_? So in each iteration of the loop you remove all items and add a single new one. So only the last one stays in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `listView1.Items.Clear()` **inside** the loop.

So in each iteration of the loop you remove *all* items and add a single new one. So only the *last one* stays in the listview.

Move the line *before* the loop:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < DTT.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow dr = DTT.Rows[i];
    ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["desc"].ToString()); 
    listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["desc"].ToString());
    listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["enchimento"].ToString());
    listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pl

```html
Please use like below ExP:

   string InputValue="12";

        List<string> listView1 = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            List<string> terms = InputValue.Split(',').ToList();
            terms = terms.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();

            //Extract the term to be searched from the list
            string searchTerm = terms.LastOrDefault().ToString().Trim();

            //Return if Search Term is empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            {
                return new string[0];
            }

            //Populate the terms that need to be filtered out
            List<string> excludeTerms = new List<string>();
            if (terms.Count > 1)
            {
                terms.RemoveAt(terms.Count - 1);
                excludeTerms = terms;
            }

           conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["CON"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                string query = "select [desc],[enchimento] from vidros where " +
                " desempenho = @emp";

                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp", searchTerm);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        listView1.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["desc"], sdr["enchimento"]));
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return listView1.ToArray();
```